# Add register to register in the same instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

Is there a way to accomplish the equivalent of the following, without repeating the same instruction twice?  Hopefully more efficiently.

```
add si, cx
add si, cx
```

Comment: Adding two registers is as "effectively" as we can get. You will have a hard time finding any instructions that are faster or shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent without repeating same instruction:

```
  shl cx, 1
  add si, cx
```

Not a lot of point, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Not on an x8086

Answer (score 1):

In 16, 32 or 64bit mode of a 386 or later:

```
lea    esi, [esi + ecx*2]  ; shortest in 32bit mode.  (one prefix in 64b mode: address size)

lea    esi, [rsi + rcx*2]  ; shortest encoding in 64bit mode (no prefixes)

lea    si,  [esi + ecx*2]  ; shortest encoding in 16bit mode (one prefix: address size)
```

It **doesn't matter if the upper bits of either register are zeroed**, since we're not multiplying them together.  **Carry/borrow only propagates left** (from LSB to MSB), and scaling by 2 isn't a problem either.  (No bits from the high part come down into the low part)

---

After much correction by helpful commenters, I found out that 16 bit addressing modes don't allow using `cx` as part of an addressing mode at all.  This restriction applies even in 32bit mode with an address-size prefix.  This precludes use of LEA on CPUs that don't support 32bit addressing modes, but it should be fine for 16bit DOS or boot-time code on a modern CPU.

```
;; invalid even in 32bit mode (with address-size prefix)
lea    si, [si + cx*2]  ;  invalid
lea    si, [cx]         ;  invalid
```

Actual 8086 cores do still get used in  microcontrollers, but other than that, learning a crippled version of x86 is going to lead to learning suboptimal idioms for doing things in 32 and 64bit asm.  Pre-386 was missing several important features, like `movzx`.

---

Another way to do the calculation would be:

```
add  cx, cx   ; can run on more execution ports than shift-by-one on most CPUs
add  si, cx
```

This only helps if the original value of `cx` isn't needed afterwards.

If calculating `si` is on the critical path, but `cx` isn't, this shortens the latency of the dependency chain involving `si` by one `add` (1 cycle on everything, even P4).

Comment: The 8086 does have LEA, but its indexed addressing modes do not allow cx as one of the registers, nor does it allow scaling one of the registers.  You are confusing the 16 bit x8086 for the 32 bit x386 instruction sets.   Yes, 8086 cores get used as microcontrollers; you can still get them: http://www.jameco.com/1/1/1111-8086-2-microprocessor-16-bit-32-i-o-8mhz-dip-40.html   I think the 8086 instruction set is popular in assembly language classes, too, at least from the questions I often see on SO.

Comment: that was one of the things I tried previously, and I does not work. I am using 8086.

Comment: @Ira: The question didn't say 8086, so I gave an answer that would be valid for 16bit real mode, 32bit mode, or 64bit mode, not out of confusion. I hoped it would work on an 8086, but I'm not suprised it doesn't.  I didn't know 8086 was still relevant, so thanks for the link.  I thought it just got taught because it was "simpler".  It has lots more weird restrictions on which register can do what, so learning 8086 is only good if you want to actually write for 8086, not modern CPUs.  I'd hate to see asm code written without taking advantage of the new features like movzx, and addressing modes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Even in the 16bit real mode on X86 the instruction `lea    si, [si + cx*2]` is impossible. The only way to have CX as an address operand is through using ECX like `lea si, [esi + ecx*2]. It would require zeroing the high words of ECX and ESI.

Comment: @Fifoernik: thanks, I didn't realize that 16bit addressing modes were more restrictive than their 32bit equivalents.  Even in 32bit mode, yasm won't assemble `lea  si, [si + cx]`.  updated my answer with a fix.

Comment: @Ira: the upper bits don't have to be zeroed, so on a CPU that does support 32bit addressing modes with the full selection of registers, a single LEA is still all that's needed to set `esi` (or just `si` if desired).